# Xcode 4: Iphone - Adding a table view to an existing project

Tags: xcode, tableview, navigationbar

I'm new to programming IOS and I'm creating a small App for our College. This app consists of a main view that has a couple of buttons to open different things (Map, Welcome message from the Dean, Intro video, etc...). One of these buttons will open a table view that will show our 5 campuses. When they select a campus it will open a UIWebView that shows the information about that campus.

My problem is that I was able to add a nib to my project and place a tableview object in that nib. It displays, but I,m not able to get the navigation bar  or navigation button to show.

Would you have any site or suggestions?
Thanks
Ren

Answer (score 0):

You should try using an Navigation Controller. When you connect the other views to it, it will automatically add the bar and the button.

Good luck!